# Weights not being updated using Dist-Keras

Tags: python, apache-spark, deep-learning, keras, data-science-experience

As explained [here](https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras/issues/30), when I run through the example notebook, my weights are never updated after training:

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()
trained_model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

Both give me the same weights (as if the model was not trained at all):

```
[array([[-0.39513412, 0.26937097, -0.36478603, 0.30427128, -0.13985097,
-0.22316453, 0.13130313, -0.08426034],
[ 0.41418487, -0.46847233, 0.58078319, -0.63027477, -0.45647684,
-0.325973 , 0.22211522, 0.55291325],
[ 0.54379755, -0.30091569, -0.02049094, -0.4734239 , -0.41363743,
-0.38102722, -0.19341171, -0.36358535],
[-0.08354402, 0.39400059, 0.04485017, -0.1212253 , 0.07950532,
0.37202805, 0.30843312, -0.25526762]], dtype=float32),
array([ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

I am using [Data Science Experience](https://datascience.ibm.com).  Has anyone gotten this package to work on this platform?

Comment: thank u .. it works

Answer (score 0):

[My issue was due to my parameters](https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras/issues/30).  My data set was small so I needed to decrease batch size and increase epochs.  I hope this helps someone else.